# placeholder issue with setValue

Tags: angular, typescript

in input when a person writes age I am sending this value as a date (API is built like that).
I am using setValue for sending form value, but it changes the placeholder too when you submit a form.
I want the placeholder not to change.

here is my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-starter-6xojcb?file=app/app.component.ts)

**.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      formArray: this._formBuilder.array([
        this._formBuilder.group({
          birthDate: ["", [Validators.min(18), Validators.max(50)]]
        })
      ])
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    const birthDateValue = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("birthDate").value;
    const birthDateValueControl = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
      .at(0)
      .get("birthDate");
    const date = new Date();
    const year = date.getFullYear() - birthDateValue;
    date.setFullYear(year);
    birthDateValueControl.setValue(date.toISOString());

    console.log(date.toISOString());
    console.log(this.formGroup.value);
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean by placeholder? because for me the placeholder is "Age" and it doesn't change. Do you maybe mean the value inside the input?

Comment: Hi, when you type age and submit a form, placeholder changes.

Comment: I still don't understand, what behavior do you expect? after you write an age and you submit it, what do you want to show in the input?

Comment: Age that was typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just remove this line of code:

```
birthDateValueControl.setValue(date.toISOString());
```

And consequently also this line of code because it wouldn't be used anymore:

```
const birthDateValueControl = (this.formGroup.get("formArray") as FormArray)
  .at(0)
  .get("birthDate");
```

Then in the variable `date` you will find the string value of the birth date you're looking for to use it for your API call.

Try that out in the stackblitz you provided.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i updated my stackblitz with my api call, how can i include formatted date with my api call?now  when i submit it it has only age

Comment: I don't see any api call in your stackblitz, if this answer is the solution to your question just close the question and possibly open another one.

I also suggest to start making some research online and read the documentation of the tools you're using before opening a question here.

Comment: If the service is your api call just pass the data to that call: this.service.calculate(data)...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not the placeholder, it's the value that displayed.
You use the same property to store two different type of values, once it's numbers that represent years, and then after the transformation it holds a string the is a date.

To solve this just don't use the same property for two types of data.
If needed create another property (or a new object before sending to the server), One for the user input - Age, and the other for the calculated value - birth date.

Comment: sry, how can i do that?